# ansible variable reference : unable to read stdout_lines from register variable after ssh and command

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team,
My task is running she’ll commands on hosts that are pulled from registered variable. Currently two hosts but there will be 100 in production. 
am unable to read out stdout or stdout_lines. my task and output is below. Its sshing to the remove server and then runnning df -h command and storing output.

actual output ( with some texts stripped but not any brackets)

```
ok: [localhost] => {
        "raid_info.results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                "changed": true, 
                "cmd": "ssh -F /home/svcngcctal.net \"df -kh /raid/\"", 
                "delta": "0:00:02.095839", 
                "end": "2019-10-24 22:55:38.323679", 
                "failed": false, 
                "failed_when_result": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "ssh -F /home/metal.net \"df -kh /raid/\"", 
                        "_uses_shell": true, 
                        "warn": true
                    }
                }, 
                "item": {
                    "nodeType": "4.15.0-45-generic", 
                    "node_name": "hostB"
                }, 
                "rc": 0, 
                "start": "2019-10-24 22:55:36.227840", 
                "stderr": "Warning: Permanently***", 
                "stderr_lines": [
                    "Warning:asd"
                ], 
                "stdout": "Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on\n/dev/sdb1       7.0T  175G  6.5T   3% /raid", 
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on", 
                    "/dev/sdb1       7.0T  175G  6.5T   3% /raid"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                "changed": true, 
                "cmd": "ssh -F /home/svcngcc/jenkinstal.net \"df -kh /raid/\"", 
                "delta": "0:00:02.115591",
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "ssh -F /home/sal.net \"df -kh /raid/\"", 

                        "warn": true
                    }
                }, 
                "item": {
                    "nodeType": "4.15.0-45-generic", 
                    "node_name": "hostA"
                }, 
                "rc": 0, 
                "start": "2019-10-24 22:55:38.467007", ", 
                "stderr_lines": [
                    "Warning: Permanently "
                ], 
                "stdout": "Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on\n/dev/sdb1       7.0T  176G  6.5T   3% /raid", 
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on", 
                    "/dev/sdb1       7.0T  176G  6.5T   3% /raid"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

from above output am not able to read stdout lines to verify the mount point..

task:

```
      - name: "RAID mount check for fscache on GPU Nodes"
        shell: ssh -F {{ ssh_cfg_path.stdout }} {{ item.node_name }}.{{ ssh_host }} "df -kh /raid/"
        ignore_errors: no
        register: raid_info
        failed_when: raid_info.rc != 0
        with_items: "{{ gpu_nodes }}"

      - name: raid_info results1_stdout_lines
        debug:
          var: raid_info.results[1].stdout_lines
```

does not output anything..

Comment: That output has been modified - there are a number of errors making it invalid. Are you able to show the actual output from `- debug: var=raid_info.results`?

Comment: You are right: for brevity I did that. updated the output now with equal brackets. however, i did strip off unnecessary info. 9 brackets each. ][ and }{

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your results - I believe that you left out some information when posting.

For example, do your tasks by any chance run on different hosts? The "raid_info" variable is registered per host, so if your tasks run on different hosts this might cause your issue.

My test, with a similar loop:
- playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - packages.yml

  tasks:
  - name: Run a command
    command: "echo {{item}}"
    register: my_output
    loop: 
    - 10.10.80.193
    - 10.10.80.194

  - name: Print the results
    debug:
      var: my_output

  - name: Print only the second item in the list
    debug:
      var: my_output.results[1].stdout_lines
```

- result:

```
# ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Run a command] *********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=10.10.80.193)
changed: [localhost] => (item=10.10.80.194)

TASK [Print the results] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_output": {
        "changed": true, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [ 
            { <snip>
            }, 
            { <snip>
            }
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Print only the second item in the list] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_output.results[1].stdout_lines": [
        "10.10.80.194"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: My task is running shell commands on hosts that are pulled from registered variable. Currently two hosts but there will be 100 in production.

Comment: So does my example - it is running shell commands on a host (in this case, localhost). If you are running tasks on multiple hosts, please note that registered variables are registered per host (as mentioned in my answer above). So you will need to get the result from the correct host (either by running the second task on the same host, or by using `hostvars[]`)

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer then in my case where am running shell commands on all hosts how would my Task look?

Comment: Awesome!. I had to set debug on raid_info like you did in your task and then I was able to get it. But one question is as scale how should I manage this? Coz I will be having 100 nodes. I can’t be printing debug 100 times. Can I loop in debug?

Comment: The debug is only there for you (and me), so that during troubleshooting we can see the variables and their contents. For production, you will replace the `debug` module with one that does an actual action :) . And to answer the final question, yes, of course - `debug` is just another module, and you can loop when using it just fine.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how to get task run for 100 hosts as my above task runs only for two hosts. Any hint? Can you paste a sample task

Comment: You simply need to change the loop variable (in my case, it is a list with two elements - in your case, it can be a list with 100 :) ). If you store your hosts in a variable called "hostlist", just use `loop: "{{hostlist}}"` in the first task. In order to give you a more complete example, I will need to know how you get your list of hosts, and where you store it.

Comment: This was the only answer which worked for me as of today and `ansible` `2.9.6`. Thank you